# How is the following Javascript expression being evaluated?

Tags: javascript, expression

```
[-1,1][+!!boolean]
```

I was debugging a JS code where I found this line. As the name implies, var boolean could have either true or false value.

Comment: Where did you find code like that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh, that's disgusting. Here's what's going on:

```
!!boolean
```

This turns `boolean` into a true/false boolean. The `!` is the negation, so when you do two, you force the negation of the negation, or the boolean value of the original. Basically, it does:

```
var x = boolean;
if (x) {
    x = true;
} else {
    x = false;
}
```

The `+` turns the right side into a number. `+true` -> `1` and `+false` -> `0`.

The first bit is an array. It's indexing that array literal by whatever is on the right side.

In short, if `boolean` is true, it will grab the second element, otherwise the first.

```
[-1,1][+!!true] === 1
[-1,1][+!!false] === -1
```

A much less terrible version of this (using the ternary):

```
var x = boolean ? 1 : -1;
```

Or abuse of `&&` and `||`:

```
var x = (boolean && 1) || -1;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ! Actually I was going through a code of plugin and no matter how disgusting that line looks to you now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The first bit creates an array with two values:

```
[-1,1]
```

The second bits ensures that "boolean" is actually a boolean value by doing a double-inversion:

```
!!boolean == boolean
```

The plus-operator is used to transform this boolean into a number, where `true => 1` and `false => 0`.

Eventually, this number is used to pick one of the two values in that array, i.e. this expression turns "true" into 1 and "false" into -1.

However, this might be a bit more readable:

```
boolean ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: And far fewer characters too!

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[-1,1]` is an array containing the values `-1` and `1`.

The second set of brackets fetches a value from the array. e.g., if `x` is an array, then `x[0]` fetches the first element. if we write `y = [-1,1][0]`, this is the same as the following:

```
var x = [-1,1];
y = x[0];
```

So, now what about `+!!boolean`?
Well, `!` converts a value to a boolean if it is not "falsy". And applying `!` again converts it `true` if it is truthy, and `false` if it falsy. (I recommend [this google search](http://google.com/search?q=javascript%20truthy%20and%20falsy) on the terms truthy and falsy)

Lastly, the `+` (positive) operator converts it to a number. Think about it as the opposite of the `-` (negative) operator. So `+true` converts to `1` and `+false` converts to `-1`.

If you were to take the expanded form of it and write it as a function, this would be it (in my opinion):

```
function( value ){
    var  output_values  =  [ -1, 1 ]
      ,  boolean        =   !!value
      ,  index          =    +boolean
      ;        
    return output_values[ index ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to select one element from first array, based on a variable :

```
[-1,1][INDEX BASED ON BOOLEAN VALUE]
```

The code is equivalent to :

```
var myArr = [-1,1];
var selected = null;
if(boolean === false ){
     selected = myArr[0];
}
else {
     selected = myArr[1];
```

}

Explaination :

`[+!!boolean]` will return  0 or 1 based on value of boolean , double negation has been done to convert all falsy values like false,empty array, undefined , empty object to boolean false, and truthy values to boolean true.
Putting a `+` in front of them typecasts them into an integer, thus making it a valid index either 0 or 1, for the targent array [-1,1]